# How to make one function wait until another function happen then complete exctution on javascript

Tags: javascript

Consider I have two javascript functions sum and multiply defined as follow :

```
function sum(a, b){
    res1 =  a + b;
    return res1;
}

function multiply(x, y){
     res2 = x * y;
     console.log(res2);
}
```

Then i make another caller function like this, suppose we have a `button` already defined

```
function caller(){
    button.addEventListener('click', function(){
         z = sum();
         console.log(z);
    }) 
    multiply();
}
```

i want the caller function to stop excution utill the click event happen and log the value of (z) then call the multiply function. 
how to do that in javascript?

Comment: Just move `multiply()` into event handler

Comment: Javascript runs completely synchronously, you'll have to leverage callbacks (or promises/Observables) for asynchronous workflows.

Comment: You should checkout javascript `Promises` and `async await`. But in this example you can achieve that. Without them

Comment: I try to use async/await but i don't know how to do that, can you show me how ?

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded and imperative.  When you execute two operations in sequence, the second one doesn't execute until the first one completes.  Are you executing asynchronous operations?  What specifically are you doing?

Answer (score 3):

Just put the `multiply()` call inside the callback function:

```
function caller(){
    button.addEventListener('click', function(){
         z = sum();
         console.log(z);
         multiply();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to make one function wait until another function happen then complete exctution on javascript?

The answer is you cannot.

Javascript is executed on a **single thread** and **doesn't allow blocking**.

You must leverage callbacks (they come in many forms) in order to achieve asynchronous workflows.

In fact your function is exactly this, see:

```
function caller(){
    button.addEventListener('click', function(){
         z = sum();
         console.log(z);
    }) 
    multiply();
}
```

The function containing `console.log(z);` does not run when `addEventListener` is run, instead the function is saved so that it can be called later.

If you want to see this in action run the following and watch the order of the console logs.

```
function caller(){
    button.addEventListener('click', function(){
         z = sum();
         console.log('2');
    }) 
    console.log('1');
    multiply();
}
```